# How to propagate between aspects

Tags: bazel, bazel-aspect

I am applying aspects but somehow seem to do something wrong.
Imaging the famous reference picture.

[image]

In my case **A**  is:

```
deps_aspect = aspect(
    implementation = _deps_aspect_impl,
    attr_aspects = ["resource_deps"],
    attrs = {
    },
)
```

For **A(W)**, `_deps_aspect_impl` returns:

```
    return struct(
        dep_files = set(),
    )
```

Now, if I understood the documentation correctly, I should be able to access **A(W)** `dep_files` via `resource_deps` in **A(Y)**.

If for **A(Y)**, `_deps_aspect_impl` I do:

```
print("DIR: %s" % dir(ctx.rule.attr))
```

There is no `resource_deps` printed (and I cannot access it).

Am I understanding something wrong or how is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I did not catch various nuances right.

1. `attr_aspects` are recursive. Which means once you apply, they propagate downwards the graph. So the attributes are global for that one apply. Perhaps it would be better to be able to specify a dict with `kind` -> `attr` mapping.
2. Due to 1. you really need to have a look at `kind`, so you have different code paths (the one thing I did right).
3. Data can **NOT** be propagated via the shadow graph. I imagined that before. You can only propagate on "solid" rule `attrs`.